# Facebook App Links with branch.io

Tags: android, branch.io

I'm having trouble integrating Facebook App Links with branch.io.  I tried the following code to show the App Invite in our android app:

```
if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
    AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
        .setApplinkUrl("https://bnc.lt/raise-test-ios")
        .build();
    AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
}
```

As you can see for the App Link URL I used our generated branch.io marketing url, but I get the following when running:

[image]

Anyone know what's going on here, I thought we could just use our Branch URL as the App Link URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what's wrong with the OG tags at the end of the link by using the Facebook OG tester. If everything is working, you'll see all the AppLinks appear in the scrape results. If not, it shows you an error. Try it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

It seems for that particular link, you still needed to specify OG title, description and stuff before Facebook will parse the page properly. You can add that into the Branch marketing link on [dashboard.branch.io](https://dashboard.branch.io/?bmp=so-ac). Or when you create the Branch Link dynamically, just make sure to use $og_title, $og_description and $og_image_url.

Once you get it integrated from there, you can start seeing the install/open counts tick up from the AppInvites. We just wrote a full guide on how to use Branch for this feature in case it's helpful:
https://dev.branch.io/recipes/facebook_appinvites/ios

Hope this helps!